# How to consume message From RabbitMQ in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, rabbitmq

I am new learner trying to understand rabbitmq in Laravel. I have found driver [vyuldashev/laravel-queue-rabbitmq](https://github.com/vyuldashev/laravel-queue-rabbitmq)

I already configure app/queue.php and run the driver with this syntax "php artisan queue:work rabbitmq". the question is how i can consume the message so i can use the data for my service. with Queue i have to dispatch the Job in my controller. I wont dispatch the Job in my controller because laravel just listen the message and process the message. Anybody can help me to explain how thi work? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When dispatching Jobs using:

```
MyJob::dispatch();
```

they get scheduled to be processed, the worker that you started using:

```
php artisan queue:work
```

will start processing the dispatched job if it has no job to process. The worker will execute the `handle` method of the dispatched job.

```
class MyJob {
  public function handle(){
     // Any logic here will be executed.
  }
}
```